# Including JavaScript files on the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript

Does loading JavaScript files on the bottom of a page really help to speed up the page?

Comment: putting your script tags at the end of the html document will give the browser the chance to 1st render the html page and then run the javascript code. Making it faster though, that depends on what you want to speed up, this might possibly load some html content faster if that's what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. Assuming you implement it correctly. It allows the rest of your markup to render before it tries downloading the file. [As Paul Irish said, "Friends don't let friends put script tags in the head"](https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/416759189961072640)

Additional Resources:

[Yahoo Developer Network](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom=)

[Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)

[Another Google Developers Article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript#parser-blocking-vs-asynchronous-javascript)

[Ilya Grigorik](https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/#comment-1398899164)

[Jake Archibald Tweet](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/574604419825823745)